# Can't build and weird intellisense in VS due to adding unrelated extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I had this extension method

```
public static List<Models.SomeObject> ToServiceModel(this List<SomeObject> source)
{
    return source
        .Select(s => s.ToServiceModel())
        .ToList();
}
```

where SomeObject is a 3rd-party object and Models.SomeObject is the service model version of it and everything worked fine.

Then I added this extension method

```
    public static List<UnrelatedObject> ToServiceModel(this List<Data.Models.UnrelatedObject> source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<List<Data.Models.SqueezePage>, List<SqueezePage>>(source);
    }
```

where Data.Models.UnrelatedObject is a Code First object and UnrelatedObject is the service model.

But when I type `new List<UnrelatedObject>().ToServiceModel()`, I get two options for the intellisense, one for each extension method. The compiler also results in an error saying I need to include a reference for the first type, which is wrong cause obviously the type doesn't belong.

Even if I type `new List<int>().ToServiceModel` I get the option for the first one (and another extension method), but not the second one.

Can this have something to do with co-variance or contra-variance? How do I stop all this extra intellisense and compiler confusion so the extension methods are only valid on the targeted type?

**UPDATED:**

I've changed the title and now let me try to refocus the problem on compilation instead of intellisense.

```
The type '{0}' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly '{1}'.
```

Project A references Project B which references Assembly C. Project A is demanding a reference to Assembly C even though I'm not directly using any types in Assembly C.

I have verified that everything compiles find without the above mentioned extension method, but once I add it and build, then I get the assembly issue. I have verified that the models used in the extension method use types of the Project D, with no connection to Assembly C and a type that is a POCO and only uses .NET types.

So why would adding an unrelated extension method to Project B cause Project A to suddenly want a reference it doesn't need?

Comment: Do you use ReSharper? a similar thing has started happening in my machine since I upgraded to R# 8

Comment: I'm on ReSharper 7, with most of their intellisense turned off. But this isn't just intellisense, I'm getting compiler errors.

Comment: I finally gave into the error message and referenced the "unneeded" assembly. It works now. I still don't understand why that reference needed to be added.

Comment: I ran into this again. Would really like to find an answer.